# How do we add query strings to NavLink?

Tags: reactjs

What's the proper way to add a query string to NavLink? Currently, I'm doing it like this

```
<NavLink to="/payment/Yearly4499FreeTrial?gift=true">
```

Notice the gift=true

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: This looks valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proper" way is definitely subjective. The `to` prop only accepts a string, unlike some URL builders or anchor components available that take an object of query params. I personally find an object of key/values better structured, but again it's subjective.

Some options are:

*ES6*

```
const qs = Object.keys(params).map(key => key + '=' + params[key]).join('&');
```

*query-string module (NPM)*

```
const qs = queryString.stringify(params);
```